# Re-attach logcat window

Tags: android-studio

I don't know how but I somehow unattached the logcat window in AS. You can see in the following picture that all I'm left with is this nyan-cat button that now opens logcat.

[image]

After clicking this button I'm just getting a *always-on-top*-window of logcat:

[image]

How can I undo this? Re-install AS does not count as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just dragging it?

[image: Try this]

Comment: It appears like I am no man for google/android products .. maybe I should just go back to ai ..

Comment: I've spent 4 hours today trying to link GLFW and GLEW on CMake -and failed-. I feel the new framework pain too.